# Java code duplication refactoring

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I use codeclimate to statically analyze my java code. The output says: `Similar blocks of code found in 3 locations. Consider refactoring.`

What could be the best way to refactor the following code without repeat myself and not losing the "code readability":

```
public String getString(String component, String key, String defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    try {
      SingleRequestData config = clientRest.target(this.configServiceUrl).path(CONFIG_ENDPOINT).path(component)
          .path(key).path(defaultValue).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<SingleRequestData>() {
          });
      logger.log(Level.INFO, "Fetched Remote config: {0}={1} for Component: {3}",
          new Object[] { key, config.value, component });
      return config.value;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "{0} : {1}", new Object[] { e.getMessage(), ERROR_MESSAGE });
      throw new ConfigException(e.getMessage() + " " + ERROR_MESSAGE, e.getCause());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Integer getInteger(String component, String key, int defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    try {
      String value = this.getString(component, key, String.valueOf(defaultValue));
      return Integer.parseInt(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new ConfigException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Double getDouble(String component, String key, double defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    try {
      String value = this.getString(component, key, String.valueOf(defaultValue));
      return Double.parseDouble(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new ConfigException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean getBoolean(String component, String key, boolean defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    try {
      String value = this.getString(component, key, String.valueOf(defaultValue));
      return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new ConfigException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a generic method that calls `getString` and uses custom parser (defined as functional interface in this case) to parse the string into a generic type:

```
public <T> T getValue(String component, String key, T defaultValue, Function<String, T> parser) throws ConfigException {
    try {
        String value = this.getString( component, key, String.valueOf(defaultValue) );
        return parser.apply(value);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ConfigException( e.getMessage(), e.getCause() );
      }
}

public Integer getInteger(String component, String key, int defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    return getValue(component, key, defaultValue, Integer::parseInt );
}

public Double  getDouble(String component, String key, double defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    return getValue(component, key, defaultValue, Double::parseDouble );
}

public Boolean getBoolean (String component, String key, boolean defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    return getValue(component, key, defaultValue, Boolean::parseBoolean);
}
```

Comment: nearly identical solutions posted at the same time :)

Comment: It really is (upvoting yours too). I am sure we have written config library like this many times in the past:)

Answer (score 4):

We could write a private generic method
introducing `T` for `T defaultValue` and `Function<String, T> parser`:

```
private <T> T getT(String component, String key, T defaultValue, Function<String, T> parser) {
    try {
        return parser.apply(this.getString(component, key, String.valueOf(defaultValue)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new ConfigException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}
```

The methods `getInteger`, `getDouble`, `getBoolean` would call it passing their `Function<String, T>`:

```
public Integer getInteger(String component, String key, int defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    return getT(component, key, defaultValue, Integer::parseInt);
}

public Double getDouble(String component, String key, double defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    return getT(component, key, defaultValue, Double::parseDouble);
}

public Boolean getBoolean(String component, String key, boolean defaultValue) throws ConfigException {
    return getT(component, key, defaultValue, Boolean::parseBoolean);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually too many exceptions are (re-)thrown and caught. And Exception is too unspecific.

For refactoring one might consider dropping the throws.

Certainly for getInteger and getDouble (that call getString), catching the exception does not make sense.

```
  @Override
  public Integer getInteger(String component, String key, int defaultValue)
              throws ConfigException {
      return Integer.parseInt(getString(component, key, String.valueOf(defaultValue)));
  }
```

For Java 8 another pattern emerges in some projects:

```
public Optional<String> getString(String component, String key) throws ConfigException { ...

public Optional<Integer> getInteger(String component, String key) throws ConfigException {

int value = getInteger(component, key).orElse(defaultValue);
```

Comment: Agree here that catching generic exception in specific `get` method is wrong. It can either not catch anything and let parse methods throw exception (such as `NumberFormatException`) to client code or catch those exceptions only.